# Django create db view with multiply between cols, take average and group by time

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model as below:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True,
                                auto_now_add=True)
    curr_1 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    volt_1 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    curr_2 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    volt_2 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    curr_3 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    volt_3 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)

class AvgPower(models.Model):
    ...
```

Now I want to create a db view for above table group by day with cols as below:

```
power_1 = avg(curr_1 * volt_1)
power_2 = avg(curr_2 * volt_2)
power_3 = avg(curr_3 * volt_3)
```

Can any one tell me how to create view with "group by", multiply and average along time?

=======================================================================

Part of Ans:

```
Source.objects
.filter(time_r__date__gte=(date.today()-timedelta(days=1)))
.annotate(p1=F('curr_1')*F('volt_1'),p2=F('curr_2')*F('volt_2'))
.values('time_r__date')
.annotate(p1a=Avg('p1'),p2a=Avg('p2'))
```

where

`time_r__date` : extract date from datetime field

`time_r__date__gte` : greater than or equal to

`(date.today()-timedelta(days=1))` : both from `datetime`, get yesterday's date

`annotate(p1=F('curr_1')*F('volt_1'),p2=F('curr_2')*F('volt_2'))` : compute pow from curr and volt for each row

`values('time_r__date')` : group by `time_r__date`

`annotate(p1a=Avg('p1'),p2a=Avg('p2'))` : get average for each group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use F()expression with annotate and aggregate. Source.objects.filter(day=1).annotate(power_sum=F('curr_1') * F('volt_1'),power_sum2=F('curr_2') * F('volt_2')
                                                    ).aggregate(Avg('power_sum'),Avg('power_sum2'))

Comment: is django won't support 'view' table having pre-calculate result?